# displays all the values that are above the average and also gives the positions of these values in the list

Tags: python

Hi i'm new in programming python language and i have a trouble finding to displays all the values that are above the average and also gives the positions of these values in the array.

Here is the whole question:
2.  Write a program that allows the input of a number of positive integer values (terminated by a sentinel value) and places them in a list. The program then calculates the average of the values and displays all the values that are above the average and also gives the positions of these values in the array.

I've written the code and only the average part is working and i don't know why the loop is not working.Here it is the code:

```
listA=[]
x=eval(input("enter a number:"))
count=0

def average(listA):
    sum=0
    for i in range(len(listA)):
    sum=sum+listA[i]
    average_of_num=sum/count
    return average_of_num

while (x>0):
    listA.append(x)
    count=count+1
    x=eval(input("enter a number:"))

z=average(listA)
print("The average is:",z)

for i in range(len(listA)):
    if (listA[i] > z):
        print=("the number:",listA[i],"is greater than average and its position is",i)
```

Can you help me please because i have a test in two days on programming assessing the topic of list and this type of question is expected. Thanks

Comment: As it is your code example does not even start, it has indentation errors and it will produce errors on execution. Polish it before posting it.

Comment: For the love of gravy, __*never*__ use `eval` on user input without sanitizing it.  What would happen if the user entered `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` to keep track of the position in a list while iterating through it.

```
def average(listA):
    return sum(listA)/len(listA)

listA=[]
x=int(input("enter a number:"))

while (x>0):
    listA.append(x)
    x=int(input("enter a number:"))

z=average(listA)
print("The average is:",z)

for pos, i in enumerate(listA):
    if i >  z:
        print("the number", i, "is greater than average and its position is",pos)
```

You had `print=(...` which assigns a value to the variable `print`.

Comment: okay
that was such a mistake putting the equal sign. thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I think the following demonstrates what you're after.

```
>>> listA = [1,6,10,12,4,45,2,4,5,7,8]
>>> avg = sum(listA)/len(listA)
>>> counts = {}
>>> for ind, val in enumerate(listA):
        counts.setdefault(val,[]).append(ind)
>>> large_nums = {num: indicies for num, indicies in counts.items() if num > avg}

>>> print(avg)
9.454545454545455

>>> print(large_nums)
{10: [2], 12: [3], 45: [5]}
```

And again, ***never*** use `eval` on unsanitized user input.

Comment: thank you for the code and the advice.much appreciated :)

Comment: Appreciation can be expressed via upvoting :)